# How do I provide success messages asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How do I provide success messages in asp.net mvc?

Comment: success for what? what do you mean by message? what are you trying to accomplish? help us help you.

Answer (score 19):

If you're displaying a message on a different page than `ViewData` won't help you, since it's reinitialized with each request. On the other hand, `TempData` can store data for two requests. Here's an example:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(SomeModel someModel)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //do something
                TempData["Success"] = "Success message text.";
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["Error"] = "Error message text.";
                return View(someModel);
            }
        }
```

Inside `if` block you must use `TempData` because you're doing redirection (another request), but inside else you can use `ViewData`.

And inside view you could have something like this:

```
@if (ViewData["Error"] != null)
{
    <div class="red">
        <p><strong>Error:</strong> @ViewData["Error"].ToString()</p>
    </div>
}
@if (TempData["Success"] != null)
{
    <div class="green">
        <p><strong>Success:</strong> @TempData["Success"].ToString()</p>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: There really isn't need to re-implement error handling, as it's is already built-in through ModelState.AddModelError(). Besides writing less code, you get better control on exactly where you want your validation errors to appear (Html.ValidationSummary() and Html.ValidationMessageFor()). Also, using validation frameworks/plugins become easier to hookup because they also adhere to the ModelState standard.

Comment: @Daniel I agree, but question was about success message not validation error ;)

Comment: I recommend this type of message view in master page.

Answer (score 13):

in your controller, you can do this:

```
ViewData["Message"] = "Success"
```

and in your view you you can check if there is a message to display, and if so than display it:

```
@if (ViewData["Message"] != null)
    <div>success</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use ViewData to store success messages.  Create the success message in the Controller and check for it in the View.  If it exists, render it.

Answer (score 2):

TempData can be used like a dictionary.
Each saved value lasts for the current and the next request.
Perfect for redirects.

```
this.TempData["messages"] = "Success!";
return RedirectToAction("YourAction");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ViewData["success"]` or `ViewData["error"]`

for instance:

```
public ActionResult saveResult()
{
    var num = 1;
    //After action was completed;
    if ( num == 1 ) {
        ViewData["success"] = "Action completed successfully";
    }else{
        ViewData["error"] = "OOps Action not completed";
    }

    return RedirectoAction("Index");
}
```

on the page you want to check if submission was successful

```
@if ( ViewData["success"] != null ) 
{
    <div class="alert alert-success">@ViewData["success"]</div>
}

@if ( ViewData["error"] != null ) 
{
    <div class="alert alert-error">@ViewData["error"]</div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below generic approach so that it can be used to display all kind of messages like Success/Error/Info/Warning with a single implementation and can be used from any page.

[image]

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

    </head>
    <body>
        @if (TempData["UserMessage"] != null)
        {
            var message = (Models.Message) TempData["UserMessage"];
            <div class="alert @message.CssClassName alert-dismissible fade show">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
                <strong>@message.Title</strong> @message.DisplayMessage
            </div>
        }
        @RenderBody()
    </body>
</html>
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ActionMethod(ViewModel vm)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid) 
        {
            try
            {
                CommitData();
                TempData["UserMessage"] = new Message() { CssClassName = "alert-success", Title = "Success!", DisplayMessage = "Data Saved" };
                return RedirectToAction("Success");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                TempData["UserMessage"] = new Message() { CssClassName = "alert-danger", Title = "Error!", DisplayMessage = "Some Error Occured" };
                return RedirectToAction("Error");
            }
        }
        return View(vm); //return to view with model if model is not valid
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a tendency to store my errors and successes in the same array/object and pass them to the view.

Since most of my error/success message would appear in the same spot and they usually don't occur at the same time, this is usually not a problem.

I have a function called `ShowFeedback()` that is called as a usercontrol and does the logic to determine what to show. The errors and successes are marked up the same in HTML and only the css differs a bit. So you could have

```
<div id="feedback" class="error">
    Your error message
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="feedback" class="success">
    Your success message
</div>
```